# continuity in one point mean and the definition

Tags: real-analysis

this is real analysis continuity and limit section

I heard that **"function can be continuous in one point"**

this make a little sense and i can force to myself to accept it

but i want to understand this concept more naturally

=====================================================

**if a certain pint is not an isolated point it can say that its continuous in that point?**

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2):

The definition of continuity in one point is:

$$
\lim_{x\to a+} f(x) = \lim_{x\to a-} f(x) = f(a)
$$

, where those limits are lateral limits.

Translated into English, this means that for a point a, the function is continuous if a is next to the points in left and next to the points in right. So, there is no 'gap' between those points.
Another perspective would be to take a projection of f(x) on x axis and on y axis, on a vecinity of a. In order to be continuous in a, there must be no gap, no matter how small is the vecinity.

I know my explanation is not very academical, but i hope you get a better understanding of continuity.

Answer (score 1):

For example let $f:[0,1]\cup ${${2}$}$\to \Bbb R$ with $f(x)=x$. Then $f$ is continuous,because is continuous in $[0,1]$ and {$2$} is isolated point.